# DB query - how to order by absolute values?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have query that fetch data... 
I want to order it by absolute value,
current query:

```
$someVar = DB::table('tblName')->where('id', $id)->orderBy('size', 'desc')->get
```

I tried to do something like `orderBy(Abs('size'), 'desc')->get`
but it didn't work and can't find any solution in the documentations.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the method `raw` for this to work.

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('ABS(size)'), 'desc');
```

Comment: Old post, however I found something that may be useful in other situations. Eloquent also has an orderByRaw() method which would allow to by written as follows, orderByRaw('ABS(size) DESC')